# Inject correlation id in WCF out bound call(Service reference)

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-binding, outbound

My Application in .net framework calls one WCF service though service reference.
Want to pass correlation Id(unique id) to the outbound wcf service.

I'm trying to add behavior for the  correlationid. With that if it'll solve the purpose.
What is the way to achieve this

Comment: What is this correlation id used for? for example tracing the relationship between the particular request and the response. IClientMessageInspector interface could enable us to inspect the request and response on the client-side.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-messages-on-the-client

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?view=netframework-4.8